# Can we mix two colors in CSS background as gradient tool do in photoshop

Tags: css, background

I created a background in photoshop it is awesome but the problem when I open the website the background takes time to load, So I'm asking if there is a way to mix two colors in CSS background as gradient tool do in photoshop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set the css background to a gradient and produce a similiar effect as in photoshop

example gradient

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom right, red, rgba(255,0,0,0));
```